# How to put as input parameter of method ID from database instead of a number from a field usin SQLite - Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a button method that expects me to give it a value from the field that serves as the ID.

```
 async void Tapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));

        if (person != null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Name: " + person.Name + Environment.NewLine + "Person ID: " + person.PersonID, "OK");
        }
    }
```

How to replace:

```
Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text)
```

With:

```
person.PersonID
```

So not to expect an input parameter but to get an ID from the database for the respective name ?

My SQLiteHelper.cs look like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Views
{
    public class SQLiteHelper
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
        public SQLiteHelper(string dbPath)
        {
            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTableAsync<Person>().Wait();
        }

        //Insert and Update new record
        public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Person person)
        {
            if (person.PersonID != 0)
            {
                return db.UpdateAsync(person);
            }
            else
            {
                return db.InsertAsync(person);
            }
        }

        //Delete
        public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(Person person)
        {
            return db.DeleteAsync(person);
        }

        //Read All Items
        public Task<List<Person>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            return db.Table<Person>().ToListAsync();
        }


        //Read Item
        public Task<Person> GetItemAsync(int personId)
        {
            return db.Table<Person>().Where(i => i.PersonID == personId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
}

My Person object look like this:
```

using System;
using SQLite;

```
namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Views
{
   
        public class Person
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

}

My App Xaml.cs look like this:

```
public static SQLiteHelper SQLiteDb
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new SQLiteHelper(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "XamarinSQLite.db3"));
            }
            return db;
        }
    }
```

I used tabbed forms on my xamarin project and want to pass as an external parameter id from the database.
I want to completely delete the field for filling in the ID and everything happens automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, first you have to bind your text field into a Person property in your ViewModel then use the Person Object in your Event handler.

```
var bindingContext = this.BindingContext as YourViewModelName ;
var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(bindingContext.person.PersonID);
```

Comment: Whats mean "YourViewModelName" ?

Comment: I write this code: var bindingContext = this.BindingContext as Person;
            var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(bindingContext.person.PersonID);

Comment: But receive this error message: /Users/pizhev/Projects/New App/WeatherLocationInfo 0.0.3/WeatherLocationInfo/Views/Favorites.xaml.cs(73,73): Error CS1061: 'Person' does not contain a definition for 'person' and no accessible extension method 'person' accepting a first argument of type 'Person' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (WeatherLocationInfo)

Comment: Are you using a ViewModel ? if not it's better to do so , just search for how to apply MVVM pattern in xamarin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm

Comment: Person is your "Model" not your "ViewModel"

Comment: I not understand what to Add on my view model. I update my answer can you check please ?

Comment: I used tabbed forms on xamarin

Comment: When I set this code: var bindingContext = this.BindingContext as Favorites;
            var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(bindingContext.person.PersonID);

Comment: I receive the same error message, Favorites is my page ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your code suggests that you are currently calling your database (SQLLite) methods from your view (mobile app or 'Tabbed forms').

While this is doable, it does not permit binding which is exactly what you are asking for when you mentioned that you would like to use 'person.PersonID' instead of 'Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text)'

In order to do this, you need to follow a layered architecture of a mobile app where calls are made as follows:

[image]

**View:** This is the face of your mobile app, the screen you see on the phone when you open the app.

**ViewModel:** The ViewModel communicates with the View and the database and is responsible for fetching data from SQLLite and connecting or 'binding' it do the View.

**Model:** In your example, this would be the 'Person' object/class and is also used by SQLLite do create tables in the database.

**DataLayer:** To start off with, I would suggest adding this layer between ViewModel and Model. This layer will have calls like 'App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync()' or 'App.SQLiteDb.SaveItemAsync()', just so that you do not have to write this code in the ViewModel, there by keeping the ViewModel clean.

Lastly, I would recommend you familiarizing yourself with the concepts of:

- Xamarin and MVVM
- Dependency Injection

Try googling out for 'Xamarin mobile app sqlite mvvm tutorials'. There are loads out there that would explain these concepts.

All the best.